# Algorithm calculate score

Tags: algorithm

[image: My progress score bar]

I have a score like picture and 5 sections with A, B, C, D, E

Section A, I have 10 score match with 1 star. Section B, I have 20 score match with 2 star and section C with 40 score match with 3 star... When I receive 3 stars, I have 70 scores. I need help, when I have scores I need resize white bar to right match with score I have, any help ?

Comment: Would defining ranges solve your problem?

Comment: My rules: 1 star - 10 scores, 2 star - 30 scores, 3 star - 70 scores, 4 star - 150 scores, 5 star - 310 scores. And score bar is 600 width, and I can resize match with score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final int barSize = 600;
double barPercent;
double score = getScore();
// Assumed every section is 20% of barPercent
if (score >= 0 && score <= 10){
    barPercent = score / 10 * 20;
}else if (score > 10 && score <= 30){
    barPercent = 20 + (score - 10) / 20 * 20;
}else if (score > 30 && score <= 70){
    barPercent = 40 + (score - 30) / 40 * 20;
}else {...}

int result = barSize * barPercent / 100;
return result;

// test case:
// 50 score => bar=50 => result=300
```

hope it helps

Comment: My progress bar is 600 width, if I have 50 score, I need progress bar resize to center of section C, with mean my progress bar resize to 300 width

Comment: Updated and added a test case.

Comment: thanks, it works :). I think replace: int result = barSize * barPercent;
 with int result = barSize * (barPercent/100);